# React Native Reanimated 2 animating the length of an SVG Path

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-reanimated, react-native-svg, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'm trying to animate an SVG path's length form 0 to it's full length in React Native Reanimated 2. Here is my sample path:

```
const AnimatedPath = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Path);

const animatedProps = useAnimatedProps(() => {
  const path =
    `M${width * 0.182} ${height * 0.59} ` +
    `L${width * 0.443} ${height * 0.59} ` +
    `L${width * 0.443} ${height * 0.39} `;
  return {
    d: path,
  };
});

return (
  <Svg height="100%" width="100%">
    <AnimatedPath animatedProps={animatedProps} fill="none" stroke="red" strokeWidth="5" />
  </Svg>
);
```

I have tried adding some interpolation to the width of the path with no luck. I have also tried looking at the interpolatePath() implementation from Redash but it seems to take in two paths as  the output range. Anything else I should look at?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `useAnimatedStyle` instead of `useAnimatedProps`, and calculate `d` value for your `Path` component (wrapped by Animated) using `useDerivedValue`, based on some `progress` shared value which you change from 0 to 1 using `withTiming`.